# JPA query return a Map

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need my JPA query return `Map<String, Object>`.

For example if my table is :

```
Person(firstName,lastName)
```

and contains two lines :

- 'Nabil','Belakbir'
- 'John','Lenon'

I need my query return a `List` of `Map<String, Object>` .

Row 1 :

- key = firtName
- value = Nabil

--

- key = lastName
- value = Belakbir

Row 2 :

- key = firtName
- value = John

--

- key = lastName
- value = Lenon

Thanks in Advance.

Nabil

Comment: If your example the key names are duplicate. Map would overwrite those values and at the end it would result in a map with only two entries or keys first-name and last name.I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: The keys will never be the same , because they represents the database columns name (Firname , LastName , phone .....)

Comment: I my example i will have a List of 2 Map and each Map has a size of 2.

Comment: A query returns a Collection, not a Map. You have to form a query that returns the keys/values and YOU form the Map

Comment: Yes , My need is have a generic system , so i need to return also the meta Data (Column name) , i was thinking about a map , but if there is a way to return column name also in the results without a Map i am open to this . Thanks

Comment: That is what JPA Tuple result class is for, assuming your JPA provider supports it